# Symfony dynamically change config routing and security yml files

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible in Symfony to dynamically change listed yml files and somehow rerender the page so it uses the new settings.

For example I am running a page where I add a new data in database. Would it be possible that when I save the data to the database I also update the config file. Is this good practice or how would one do such thing on a real life app.

I want to avoid the creation and configuration of yml files by hand whenever one adds new data to database and would instead like to do it dynamically when the user changes something from the UI. I guess a script from the server php console would be ok to but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely avoid changing config files when a new record added to database.

I think you need to learn using parameters in Symfony routing.

For example, assume that you have a `users` table and you want every user to have a profile page. When a new user is registered with username "steven", you do not need to create a routing for "/user/steven".

You can create a routing such as `/user/{username}`. This routing will then match with every user in `users` table.

Similar logic can be applied to security roles in the database.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. For example if I now have resource_owners: property and it's configured something like this:

resource_owners:
        instance1:
            type:                instance1_type
            client_id:           instance1_id
            client_secret:       "%kernel.root_dir%/config/jira_privatekey.pem"
            base_url:            https://instance1.com

How can I add instance2: with its own properties by using your idea?

Comment: You can keep resource_owners in your database. Check the Symfony docs for details. http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: Ah great that's what I needed didn't know that you can also fetch the data from the database. I am a bit sceptical thought at what point is then config file populated and updated when you change the database.